# How to populate two collections data together like Joins in SQL

Tags: mongodb, robo3t

I'm new to MongoDB. I want a result showing 2 collections data like Joins in SQL. But here, with the below scenario I can pull up only the `table2`'s data.

Can I have both the tables data displayed?

```
var courseIds = db.getCollection('table1').find( { studentId: '347765' } ).map(function(cid){
    return cid.courseId; 
});

 db.getCollection('table2').find({ cId : {$in: courseIds}}, {name: 1, course: 1});
```

Answer (score 0):

**Mongo is not a relational database**, but you can try to aggregate those collections with a lookup. I am using the example from the documentation, because unfortunately you did not give the structure of your table1 and table2 and the connecting field.

A collection orders contains the following documents:

```
{ "_id" : 1, item" : "abc", "price" : 12, "quantity" : 2 }
{ "_id" : 2, "item" : "jkl", "price" : 20, "quantity" : 1 }
{ "_id" : 3  }
```

Another collection inventory contains the following documents:

```
{ "_id" : 1, "sku" : "abc", description: "product 1", "instock" : 120 }
{ "_id" : 2, "sku" : "def", description: "product 2", "instock" : 80 }
{ "_id" : 3, "sku" : "ijk", description: "product 3", "instock" : 60 }
{ "_id" : 4, "sku" : "jkl", description: "product 4", "instock" : 70 }
{ "_id" : 5, "sku": null, description: "Incomplete" }
{ "_id" : 6 }
```

The following aggregation operation on the orders collection joins the documents from orders with the documents from the inventory collection using the fields item from the orders collection and the sku field from the inventory collection:

```
db.orders.aggregate([
    {
      $lookup:
        {
          from: "inventory",
          localField: "item",
          foreignField: "sku",
          as: "inventory_docs"
        }
   }
])
```

Please see https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup for further Information. Please also check their general documentation: They recommend to avoid joins.